# Command to choose next tuple in the list

Tags: python, tuples

I was wondering if there are any commands to automatically select the next item in the tuple without me having to type it out?

eg.

```
nul = 0

noofvalue = 5

value = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for nul < noofvalue:

file.write(value[0])
```

what command can i use here to add 1 to 'value' such that when the file loops, instead of using value[0], it uses value[1] instead?

```
nul = nul + 1
```

I've googled for the answer and searched, but i don't understand what they are talking about since i'm extremely new to computer coding, so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: `for nul < noofvalue:` is invalid syntax

Comment: Value in your example is a list. Not a tuple. It would be a tuple if it was enclosed in `()`'s, not `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). I'll add my own example, since your example is a bit weird:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for index, value in enumerate(L):
...     try:
...         print L[index+1] # Prints the next item in the list
...     except IndexError:
...         print 'End of the list!'
... 
b
c
d
e
End of the list!
```

Comment: Can we use `StopIteration:` exception to print last message and print list from `'a'` ?

Comment: Thanks! its not exactly what i wanted but i was looking for the L[index + 1] code.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can iterate over a list or tuple in the same way:

```
for x in value:
    do_something(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First `value = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` is not [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm), it is a [list](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). In Python to iterate in for loop you can simply do like:

```
for v in value:
 print v # file.write(v)
```

(I think you have C background where we need index to access elements and iterate over arrays).

if you wants index also then use use [`enumerate( any_sequence)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function that return (index, value) pairs in list,

```
>>> list(enumerate(value))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')]
```

so you could do like:

```
for i, v in enumerate(value):
  print  i, v
```

of course if you want to use index explicitly do like:

```
index = 0 
for v in value:
 print index, v
 index += 1
```

but this is not Pythonic way so not preferable in genral.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! i'll keep in mind and avoid that way of coding in Python in future